# php and c# coding generating different result

Tags: c#, php, md5

Both php and c# produces different key that makes it difficult for my c# to coded software to activate. I have software coded on c# and trying to generate automatic keys through PHP. Please help me out. Here are my codes shared

> Note - When using hashcode of 3 digit produces different result.
> hashcode with 2 digit number is giving similar results.

in c#

```
public string GetEncryptedEmail(string strEmailAdd, int iHashCode)
        {

            char c = (char)iHashCode;
            int length = strEmailAdd.Length;
            char[] array = new char[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = (char)(strEmailAdd[i] ^ c);
            }
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(array);
            string mD5Hash = GetMD5Hash(bytes);
            if (mD5Hash.Length <= 0)
            {
               

                return "";
            }
            return mD5Hash;
        }
public string GetMD5Hash(byte[] byteInput)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] array = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(byteInput);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(array[i].ToString("X2"));
                }
                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception arg)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

in php -

```
function getEncryptedEmail($strEmailAdd, $iHashCode) {

    $c = chr($iHashCode);
    $length = strlen($strEmailAdd);
    $array = array();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $array[$i] = chr(ord($strEmailAdd[$i]) ^ ord($c));
    }
    
    $bytes = utf8_encode(implode('', $array));
    $mD5Hash = md5($bytes);

    if (strlen($mD5Hash) <= 0) {
        echo "Error in product activation.";
        return "";
    }

    return $mD5Hash;
}
```

Additional Information -

I can only change my PHP code.

Cannot change my C# code.

both giving different result

Comment: Sample inputs and outputs would be great.

Comment: The only difference between the C# result and PHP result is that the C# one uses uppercase letters because you're using `X2` rather than `x2`. There is no informational difference between the two. They are both the same value.

Comment: [C# fiddle](https://rextester.com/PTT44761) vs [PHP fiddle](https://onlinephp.io?s=ZVHbSsQwEH0v9B-GUtiULYs-FIRWVLTgP4hKTNI20CRlmopF_Hent72w85BMcmbOmcMUD13ThUE1WOG1s1ArX1qBY-eVLA3XLYt7j3P2JGUKsX7lffPspErgNwzCAChiAfcgGmRnaL5CrbK1bwgnGsov6I5FHJGPVDPfbPtezsohEDGhNznJQ7FxTq_9fh4D1liI3mL9vg7kUF4oTlACHzD_i2RT-jsXjL9Gr3oiGHx196msIDtMm66d7t0uXVWOzbF5ySbb1GFkxpb2CVxgXQHbvK-VCRTk5mJyJRoHUYlIbrWFDp0chAdOW_nm02YOUX6qRuUHtBBFp_mXZAU2IYJnaGa_Xm1EMjVyY7St25Yb_qh-OBlVB-FMlEJ2m-T_&v=8.2.5)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama the results varies when my hash codes are 3 digit like 816

Comment: I recommend you edit your question to include that

Comment: According to PHP docs, `chr` only accepts numbers in the range 0 to 255. `ord` only returns numbers in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: I'm looking. I'm a C# dev, so PHP isn't really my area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs, [`chr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) only accepts values between 0 and 255, so you need to use `mb_chr` instead.

You were unnecessarily trying to get character from `$iHashCode` at the start of the function (`$c = chr($iHashCode);`) and then trying to reverse it back to an integer within the function (`ord($c)`). Because this operation is unnecessary, I haven't upgraded it to use `mb_chr` and `mb_ord`. I've instead opted to use `$iHashCode` directly.

Now that we're making the individual array items using `mb_chr`, the result is an array of UTF8-encoded strings. Because of this `utf8_encode` isn't needed for the `$bytes =` part and we can simply join the strings using `implode` before passing them to `md5`.

I've taken the liberty of returning an uppercased version of the resulting hash so that it looks 100% identical to the C# version. This doesn't affect the value of the result as the casing of the alpha characters in a hexadecimal string doesn't make a difference.

```php
function getEncryptedEmail($strEmailAdd, $iHashCode) {

    $length = strlen($strEmailAdd);
    $array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $tmp = ord($strEmailAdd[$i]) ^ $iHashCode;
        $array[$i] = mb_chr($tmp, 'UTF-8');
    }
    
    $bytes = implode('', $array);
    $mD5Hash = md5($bytes);
    
    if (strlen($mD5Hash) <= 0) {
        echo "Error in product activation.";
        return "";
    }

    return strtoupper($mD5Hash);
}
```

You can test it online [here](https://onlinephp.io?s=ZVF_S8MwEP27hX6HoxSWsjH0j4LQiooO_A6ikjVpG2h-cEvFIX53L2mHGwsJSe7evfcuaR7c4LK0m0zrlTXQS78zLR6dl2KnuRpZcfAYT09CbKBQr_wwPFshS_jJ0ixNilGa3g9wDwSk80VBWQcER-RHAsSdxVhnEVihKHhTEyk0sPCE23odyZOk8NoRxKK4YH0r1HsJH2dmAiXQmKVCnsr0_rMdkAWSqPlLK9jZH708UF5pN1ItW602S-FsV79UgTcwiIrN8JihqTpgpz4XXAkNdTE7Dh5kO1jId4jUojLg0Iqp9cDpgb94eORtfrKL0k9oIM8Xe1l6FiUZbyfnJP5LES7Cosb1X-Uk1iPXWpl-HLnmj_KbU5dy21qdb-Cuui3rPw%2C%2C&v=8.2.5) and compare it against the C# version [here](https://rextester.com/PBOYE95804).

Comment: It's a good idea to provide the encoding explicitly to mb_chr, because otherwise it defaults to a runtime global setting, which could get very confusing. Meanwhile, it's worth noting that utf8_encode was *never* the right function here; it's not a magic "fix my UTF-8" function, but does a very specific conversion from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for the info on `mb_chr`. I've updated my answer to include that change.